# I can't access to the product although it shows it's id in the URL

Tags: reactjs, web, next.js

```
import Container from "@/app/components/Container";
import ProductDetails from "./ProductDetails";
import Reviews from "./Reviews";
import { Products } from "@/utilities/Products";

interface Iparams {
  productid?: string;
}
const $Product = ({ params } : { params: Iparams }) => {
  const productDetailsAllItems  = Products.find((item) => item.id === params.productid)
  console.log("params", params);
  return (
    <>
      <div className="h-full mt-[30px]">
        {productDetailsAllItems ? (<Container>
            <ProductDetails productProp={productDetailsAllItems}/>
            <Reviews productPropReview={productDetailsAllItems}/>
        </Container>) : (<p className="text-center">Product not found</p>)}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default $Product;
```

i am working in next on a website , when i click on the product , it needs to redirect me to the productDetails page , but it does not show the product , the JSON is fine , everything was fine until i added this line of code `const productDetailsAllItems  = Products.find((item) => item.id === params.productid)` so i can pass the variable **productDetailsAllItems** as a prop to the ProductDetails component ,i cant access to the product also the url shows the right id  whats wrong with this code , the compiler does not show any errors not the console

I tried some solutions but they do not work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using NextJs App router for your Application and you are trying to render a Client side component, You can access the query Params as follows

```js
'use client'
 
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'
 
export default function Product() {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()
 
  const product = searchParams.get('productid')
 
  // URL -> `/dashboard?productid=3df56g`
  // `productid` -> '3df56g'

  return <>product: {productid}</>
}
```

Or if you are using NextJs Pages router

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const ProductPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const query = router.query;

  // URL -> `/dashboard?productid=3df56g`
  // `productid` -> '3df56g'

  const { productid } = query
  return <>product: {productid}</>
}
```